# Emacs installed with homebrew only works in terminal

Tags: emacs, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I just installed the latest Emacs with homebrew:

```
brew install emacs --with-cocoa
```

It installed successfully, but only runs in the terminal.  When I installed it on another machine it starts a separate GUI window.  Do I need to specify additional flags?

Comment: Are you sure that you're running the version you installed via Homebrew and not the super old version that ships with OSX? Depending on how your `PATH` variable is configured you might be getting the old one. Try running `emacs --version`.

Comment: I'm making sure to run the one in /usr/local/bin directly
    "/usr/local/bin/emacs --version" gives
    GNU Emacs 24.5.1
Thanks.

Comment: A bit more weirdness:  If I run /usr/local/bin/emacs-24.5 instead of /usr/local/emacs I do get a separate window but the keyboard focus remains in the terminal window.  No matter if I click on the Emacs window, all keyboard input goes to the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

you can add it to your apps just by running the below command:

```
brew linkapps emacs
```

Doc on linkapps

> Find installed formulae that provide .app-style OS X apps and symlink
>   them
>       into /Applications, allowing for easier access

Answer (score 0):

If you're launching it from within the terminal application, you're more than likely running the emacs that ships with OS-X (v22, IIRC).

To launch the homebrew version, I created an alias in bash:

```
alias emacs='open -a /Applications/Emacs.app --args $1'
```

Then typing 'emacs' from the terminal launches the homebrew version.

Comment: Nope, I'm running /usr/local/emacs directly (which is linked to ../Cellar/emacs/24.5/bin/emacs).  I'm definitely getting version 24.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port it is not official but much better looking on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

You want [aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/).
It Just Works.